# ENTRYPOINT relative path - Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

We are able to run the docker container locally with docker file having relative path in `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
USER user1

WORKDIR /home/user1

ADD script.sh $HOME/script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./script.sh"]
```

---

When the same docker image(of above docker file) is launched from ansible tower using below task:

```
- name: Run docker container
  command: docker run --rm -e arg={{value}} 111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam:v.1
```

---

We get file not found error for `script.sh`

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Problem could be that it is not an executable `chmod` should do it and also maybe I'd change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` as default entrypoint is `/bin/sh -c`

Comment: `CMD ["./script.sh"]`

Comment: Did it work? I hope yes :)

Comment: Can you explain why `CMD [".script.sh"]` works with relative path? using ansible? here `chmod` is not the problem. Giving `ENTRYPOINT ["/a/b/script.sh"]` works but not relative path

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: I think that It's because ENTRYPOINT expects a command to run and CMD expects only arguments for ENTRYPOINT. If you don't write absolute path, it will look into all directories in `$PATH` and he cannot find it there

Comment: `$PATH` of ansible env?

Comment: PATH variable inside docker container